# Darktable : Module group icons from darkroom is missing! unable to get them back!

Tags: darktable

Darktable : Module group icons from darkroom is missing! Not sure if I pressed some shortcut...

Unable to get them back after many ties (tried deleting the dbs from the setting folder)
I am running Darktable on Window 10 by the way.

Could anyone p tell how to get them back?

[image: Missing module icons]

Answer (score 5):

To fix it go to settings, then GUI options: Show search module text entry; it should be set to: show both. Select that and restart Darktable - that fixed it for me! Posting this for record in case it helps some other Darktable user!

Comment: The option is in the settings under "Darkroom" / "Dunkelkammer" in German.